# Xcode: Switch to google api v1 to api v2 (google translate)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, google-api, google-translate

This is the parser for google translations. I switched from api v1 to api v2 (pay), but I have a problem. The translation is done in the log, but the responseStatus is 0 and not 200. You can view the log, the translation is done. On the page of Google, said in json should also appear at the top "200 OK", but does not appear. Ideas?

```
-(void)getText:(NSString *)text lan1:(NSString *)lan1 lan2:(NSString *)lan2 {
translate = [[NSString stringWithString:text] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
lanTranslate = [[NSString stringWithString:lan1] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
lanTranslated = [[NSString stringWithString:lan2] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[self performTranslation];
}
-(void)performTranslation {

responseData = [NSMutableData data];

NSString *_translation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&target=%@", lanTranslate,lanTranslated];
NSString *translation = [_translation stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=MYKEY&source=%@&q=%@",translation, translate];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

NSURLConnection *go = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[go start];


}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{
[responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
[responseData appendData:data];
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableDictionary *JSONDictionary = [responseString JSONValue];

NSLog(@"res %@  js%@",responseString, JSONDictionary);


if (JSONDictionary != nil) 
{
    NSDecimalNumber * responseStatus = [JSONDictionary objectForKey:@"responseStatus"];
    if ([responseStatus intValue] != 200) {

        **NSLog(@"responseStatus %i",(int)responseStatus);**

        return;
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *responseDataDict = [JSONDictionary objectForKey:@"responseData"];
    if (responseDataDict != nil) {
        NSString *translatedText = [responseDataDict objectForKey:@"translatedText"];
        translated = [NSString stringWithString:translatedText];    
        [viewSuperiore translate:translated];

    }
}


}
```

log

```
 res {
 "data": {
 "translations": [
 {
 "translatedText": "text to be translated"
 }
 ]
 }
 }
js{
data =     {
    translations =         (
                    {
            translatedText = "text to be translated";
        }
    );
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP status code does not seem to be part of the google translate API v2 result.

(In other words, you get a 0 in the code above because the key @"responseStatus" is not present in the JSON payload.)

Solution (works for me):
You should retrieve the status code from the request's response, returned either in the connection:didReceiveResponse: delegate or right after invoking sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error: for synchronous requests:

NSInteger responseStatus = [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response statusCode];

Hope this helps.